# Passing a variable number of arguments to a selector

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector

I would like to invoke a selector from a method containing a *vargs* parameter list. Is there a way to dynamically provide a variable of number of parameters to a selector?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you mean. Inside a method which has a `va_list` parameter, you want to a) call another method which takes a `va_list`? 2) use `performSelector:` or similar, with a selector for another method which takes a `va_list`? 4) ? `NSInvocation` is probably the answer, but it would be easier to provide a more detailed solution with a clearer question.

Comment: I was thinking that you could already pass a variable argument list to perform selector, but I don't think that you can. It looks like there are only 3 options: 0 params, 1 param, or 2 params.  If this is the case, the most sensible option is to provide a couple of overloaded methods then use Dictionaries (as suggested) for other cases.

Comment: Are you looking for `objc_msgSend()`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately when using `performSelector`, your only option for passing multiple parameters is to pass in a NSArray or NSDictionary, etc. Obviously you then have to change the receiving method's constructor to accept that new parameter-storing object.

Alternatively, you could look into using [NSInvocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsinvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: "1 or 2 parameters passed to performSelector ought to be enough for anybody" -Steve Jobs, 1996

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a NSMutableDictionary where you can have a number of parameters.